# How to start pgAdmin 4 v3

Tags: pgadmin-4

I upgrade from pgAdmin 4 v2.1 to v3 in my Windows 10 pro machine.

There is an option for me to open pgAdmin at the last step of installation.
I clicked yes and it automatically open it using my default browser. I notice the url is localhost:64548/browser. I did bookmark it.

After I restart my machine, I try to reopen pgAdmin using the same bookmark and I get below message

```
This site can’t be reached
127.0.0.1 refused to connect.
```

Is there anything I missed?

Comment: Please check if the path in your Icon is set to V2 instead of V3. (had this problem when I fix programs on win7 taskbar)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pgAdmin starts on the random port, so bookmark will not work, To start a new session just right click on the taskbar icon (right bottom corner elephant icon) and click on Start.

Comment: I checked many times, the icon was not there and reinstall won't help until I uninstall v2, v3, and v4 then reinstall v4. Thanks for your answer

Comment: sorry i mean v1, v2 and v3

Comment: As of now pgadmin4 - you can configure to start it on a fixed port. Hence can be bookmarked.

Answer (score 5):

For earlier updates I did not have to update the shortcut however for ver3.0 I did need to. You just need to locate where it was installed and make a new one like ""C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v3\runtime\pgAdmin4.exe"

Answer (score 0):

For someone like me.
I run postgres in container, and the same with pgAdmin.
I can not access pgAdmin from my Chrome.

-> Config with IP of pgAdmin_container, not `127.0.0.1` of host.

It worked with my case.